# Connecting to libvirtd uri from guest to run virsh commands on host

Tags: curl, qemu, kvm, libvirt

Is connecting to host hypervisor (using libvirt remote uri ) from guest possible ?
From the various documents online, I infer that connecting to a hypervisor uri is possible only locally(,i.e, from the host). Is this understanding correct?
Is there any other way to trigger the run of virsh commands on host from guest ?

**On host:**

```
    #virsh uri 
    qemu:///system 

    #virsh -c qemu:///system list
    Id    Name                           State
    ----------------------------------------------------
     4     guest_vm                    running
```

**On guest:**

```
    # curl qemu://user1@192.168.10.1/system -vv
    * Protocol qemu not supported or disabled in libcurl
    * Closing connection -1
      curl: (1) Protocol qemu not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libvirt does not use a HTTP/REST protocol, so your use of 'curl' here is the key problem. Libvirt uses a private binary RPC protocol, so you must always use a libvirt based application to connect to libvirtd. Your URI is right - you simply need to give it to virsh instead - eg 'virsh -c qemu://user1@192.168.10.1/system'. Libvirt supports several different methods to connect - the URI you've used will access libvirt over a TLS encrypted connection - this requires that you configure libvirtd on the host to listen on the IP address, and given it x509 certificates. If you want to avoid using TLS+x509, the simpler approach is to use the SSH tunnel with a 'qemu+ssh://.....' URI. For information about accessing libvirtd remotely see http://libvirt.org/remote.html

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. The command would look like
`virsh --connect  qemu+ssh://user1@192.168.10.1/system`

For more details please refer to http://libvirt.org/uri.html